# XPages and Bootstrap 3.3.6

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

We have developed an application with Bootstrap 3.2.0. After installing the latest ExtLib containing Bootstrap 3.3.6, the rendering has completely changed. Looking at "Basic template" of www.getbootstrap.com, it is said that 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head. Is this mandatory? Has anybody experienced similar problems with Bootstrap 3.3.6?
Best regards,
Rolf Walter

Comment: In release 16 of Extlib, Bootstrap was upgraded from 3.2.0 to 3.3.6. You can read the details about that in the documentation that is part of the release (readme.pdf). It shouldn't "completely change" your app, as the two versions are very similar, 3.3.6 mostly has a lot of bug fixes etc. Can you describe the problem in more detail, post screenshots? The question is very vague, so it is hard for anyone to help. Those meta tags are set by the Bootstrap theme in XPages, so there should be no problem there

Comment: E.g. the Bootstrap buttons, did not display as before, but as links, the Footer links of the Application Layout Control disappeared, etc.

We have a theme where <theme extends="bootstrap3.2.0" ... was changed to <theme extends="bootstrap3.3.6" ... that was the only change made after installing Bootstrap 3.3.6.

Comment: That's not the correct theme name. You should be extending the theme "Bootstrap3", as detailed in the readme documentation

Answer (score 3):

`bootstrap3.3.6` is not the correct theme name to extend. The Bootstrap theme provided by the extension library is now called `Bootstrap3`. You can see this in the theme dropdown on the xsp.properties pane. It is also detailed in the Bootstrap upgrade documentation within the readme.pdf of ExtLib release 16.

Comment: I changed in our theme to <theme extends="Bootstrap3" ..., still the same strange behaviour. I'm working on Local, and then replicating to server (with same Bootstrap version), I guess that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Are you using local web preview? Are you seeing the same problems locally and on the server? What application layout configuration are you using for the app layout control?

Comment: Using local web preview, and yes, same problem on Local and on server. Application Layout Configuration: the one containing Bootstrap something (I'm not at my office right now), I chose the one of the four I believed was the most responsive and advanced one.

Comment: On the server, if you enter the command "tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib", what gets output?

Comment: 20 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.theme.bootstrap4_9.0.1.v00_16_20160119-2239
22 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlibx_9.0.1.v00_16_20160119-2239
23 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_9.0.1.v00_16_20160128-1014
28 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational_9.0.1.v00_16_20160128-1014
46 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.1.v00_16_20160128-1014
55 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_9.0.1.v00_16_20160128-1014
60 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_9.0.1.v00_16_20160128-1014
61 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.controls_9.0.1.v00_16_20160119-2239

Comment: 66 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_9.0.1.v00_16_20160128-1014
77 <<LAZY>>    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.core_9.0.1.v00_16_20160119-2239
81 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_9.0.1.v00_16_20160128-1014

Comment: 192 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_9.0.1.v00_00_20150108-0821
211 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_9.0.1.v00_00_20150108-0821
213 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.1.v00_00_20150108-0821
241 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_9.0.1.v00_00_20150108-0821
248 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_9.0.1.v00_00_20150108-0821
279 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_9.0.1.v00_00_20150108-0821

Comment: Looks fine. You aren't trying to use the SimpleResponsiveConfiguration correct? Have you "clean"ed the app after fixing the theme. Again, you've been a bit vague on the problem, something about the buttons and links. More detail would help, including screenshots. The devil is in the detail. You can edit your original question to add more info